# How do I add build-time environment variables into application with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, gulp, angular-cli

Is there a way to evaluate something at build time, and then add it to the application during an angular-cli build process?

Use case:

I was previously building an application with gulp. You could execute something like:

```
 git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

And then, you could use `gulp-replace` to add it into the application:

```
const GIT_VERSION = "{GIT_VERSION}";
```

And finally, the compiled application would look like:

```
const GIT_VERSION = "59e5722";
```

Does angular-cli provide something to achieve this without having to revert to gulp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, have you looked into Angular2 CLI's [environment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#build-targets-and-environment-files) files?

> `ng build` can specify both a build target (`--target=production` or
>   `--target=development`) and an environment file to be used with that build (`--environment=dev` or -`-environment=prod`). By default, the
>   development build target and environment are used.
>
> The mapping used to determine which environment file is used can be
>   found in angular-cli.json:
>
> ```
> "environments": {
>   "source": "environments/environment.ts",
>   "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
>   "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
> }
> ```

**Static Solution**

Modifying these files with the values you needed in each will incorporate them into each respective build, at build-time.

For example, an environment.dev.ts might look like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://dev-api.mysite.com/v1/',
  loggingEnabled: true,
  environmentName: 'Development'
};
```

**Dynamic Solution**

If you're looking for something a little more robust/dynamic you can use a plugin like [replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file), in conjunction with the environment files,  best described in the accepted answer of [How to insert a Build Number or Timestamp at build time in AngularCLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41734257/3180489) and [Volodymyr Bilyachat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100248)'s blog post [Angular 2 - Manage application version](http://www.bilyachat.com/2017/01/angular-2-build-version.html) which would allow something along the lines of:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  version: '{BUILD_VERSION}',
  apiUrl: 'http://dev-api.mysite.com/v1/',
  loggingEnabled: true,
  environmentName: 'Development'
}
```

Comment: The Dynamic solution was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks