# Cannot find name 'require' after upgrading to Angular4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to use Chart.js within my Angular project.
In previous Angular2 versions, I have been doing this well by using a 'chart.loader.ts' which has:

```
export const { Chart } = require('chart.js');
```

Then in the component code I just

```
import { Chart } from './chart.loader';
```

But after upgrading to cli 1.0.0 and Angular 4, I get the error: "Cannot find name 'require'".

To reproduce the error:

```
ng new newapp
cd newapp
npm install chart.js --save
echo "export const { Chart } = require('chart.js');" >> src/app/chart.loader.ts
ng serve
```

In my 'tsconfig.json', I have

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
```

And in 'node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts' there is:

```
declare var require: NodeRequire;
```

So I'm confused.

BTW, I constantly encounter the warning:

```
[tslint] The selector of the component "OverviewComponent" should have prefix "app"(component-selector)
```

Though I have set the "prefix": "" in my '.angular-cli.json'. Could it because changing from 'angular-cli.json' to '.angular-cli.json' the cause?

Comment: The problem is in your tsconfig.json file. See the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require

Comment: @IndyWill Thanks, actually it should be in src/tsconfig.app.json. Can you write this as an answer?

Comment: For electron + angular 2/4 see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47364843/5248229

Answer (score 263, accepted):

The problem (as outlined in [typescript getting error TS2304: cannot find name ' require'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require)) is that the type definitions for node are not installed.

With a projected genned `with @angular/cli 1.x`, the specific steps should be:

**Step 1**:

Install `@types/node` with either of the following:

```
- npm install --save @types/node
- yarn add @types/node -D
```

**Step 2**:
Edit your **src/tsconfig.app.json** file and add the following in place of the empty `"types": []`, which should already be there:

```
...
"types": [ "node" ],
"typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ]
...
```

If I've missed anything, jot a comment and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: well didnt work for me... do i have to install something else?

Comment: Also for me it doesn't work. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421367/types-not-found

Comment: Note: You have to change `tsconfig.app.json` under `src` folder adding `"types": ["node"]`, it is not in the root tsconfig

Comment: Didn't work for me either. another answer suggesting just to add `declare var require: any;` helped surprisingly.

Comment: it worked for me but I have to remove "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ], I am using Angular 5.

Comment: in angular 8 I just added "types": [ "node" ] to tsconfig.app.json and it worked.

Comment: It did not work for me at step `- yarn add @types/node -D` because `yarn` is not a known command. Windows 10, Angular 10.

Comment: I needed to restart the `ng server` to have this working

Answer (score 40):

### Will work in Angular 7+

---

I was facing the same issue, I was adding

```
"types": ["node"]
```

to **tsconfig.json** of root folder.

There was one more **tsconfig.app.json** under **src** folder and I got solved this by adding

```
"types": ["node"]
```

to **tsconfig.app.json** file under `compilerOptions`

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]  ----------------------< added node to the array
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: simple and easy, solved my problem angular 12

Comment: The sconfig.app.json file was what I was missing (Angular 14). Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

**Finally I got solution for this, check my App module file :**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import * as highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';

import { AppRouting } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

declare var require: any;


export function highchartsFactory() {
      const hc = require('highcharts');
      const dd = require('highcharts/modules/drilldown');
      dd(hc);

      return hc;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRouting,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ChartModule
  ],
  providers: [{
      provide: HighchartsStatic,
      useFactory: highchartsFactory
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Notice `declare var require: any;` in the above code.

Comment: I had this issue in the polyfills.ts file, but your "declare var require: any;" fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 16):

Still not sure the answer, but a possible workaround is

```
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
```

Answer (score 16):

As for me, using VSCode and Angular 5, only had to add "node" to types in tsconfig.app.json. **Save, and restart** the server.

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    ..
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
  ..
}
```

One curious thing, is that this problem "cannot find require (", does not happen when excuting with ts-node

Comment: Worked like a charm in Angular 6 for me.

Comment: This solution worked for me in an Angular 6 library. I needed to add the `"types": [
      "node"
    ],` to the `tsconfig.lib.json` though.

Comment: AND RESTART SERVER. My goodness, it was this all along. Working on Angular 9. 

Answer (score 4):

I added

```
"types": [ 
   "node"
]
```

in my **tsconfig** file and its worked for me **tsconfig.json** file look like

```
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [ 
      "node",
      "underscore"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question you still might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line at the top of the file that gives the error:

```
declare var require: any
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `tsconfig.json` file into a new folder to restructure my project.

So it wasn't able to resolve the path to node_modules/@types folder inside `typeRoots` property of tsconfig.json

So just update the path from

```
"typeRoots": [
  "../node_modules/@types"
]
```

to

```
"typeRoots": [
  "../../node_modules/@types"
]
```

To just ensure that the path to node_modules is resolved from the new location of the tsconfig.json