# TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, typescript, webpack

Webpack (specifically *awesome-typescript-loader*) fails to build my app because of the following error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/app/app.ts:6:13
   TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
```

The associated code:

```
@Component({
  name: 'App',
  template: require('./app.template.pug') <---
})
export class AppComponent extends Vue {

}
```

There's a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require) which describes the exact same error, and I've tried various solutions mentioned in the answers, however with no success:

#### 1. Types are installed in `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
  " @types/node": "^7.0.22"
  ...
```

#### 2. `awesome-typescript-loader` is aware of my `tsconfig.json`:

```
loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
options: {
  configFileName: 'tsconfig.json',
  useCache: config.build.useCaching
}
```

#### 3. `Types` aswell as `type roots` have been declared in `tsconfig.json`

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"types": [
  "node",
  "webpack"
],
```

#### 4. My custom typings include definitions for node

```
declare module '*';
declare var require: any
```

Anything else I could try?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43129815/2106820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had solve this by adding a new `webpack.d.ts` and adding below content to it..

```
        declare var require: (filename: string) => any;
```