# Types not found

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I just updated angular-cli (v1.1) and created a new project using `ng new MyProj`.
Then I added and installed two dependencies to the **project.json** file:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "toastr": "2.1.2",
    "spin": "0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/toastr": "2.1.32",
    "@types/spin": "2.3.30",
    ...
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
```

Then I updated the autogenerated app.component.ts adding this constructor:

```
constructor() {
    toastr.success('Hi')
}
```

The IDE (visual studio code) do not return any error but when I serve the application using `ng serve` I get the following error:

ERROR in ../A/src/app/app.component.ts (15,5): C
annot find name 'toastr'.

I really cannot figure out what is wrong with that.

Thanks a lot

Comment: have you install this dependencies using **npm install** command?

Comment: also in angular you need to import and inject your npm modules first, follow [**angular2-toastr**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toastr) documentation for more info

Comment: Yes, I did use **npm install**. I'm not using Angular2.toastr. I'm just using the "original" js library, so it is not a module, it is just a js file.

Comment: if it is only js library then you need to include js and css in index.html file, then you can use toaster inside any component, without including it would not work

Comment: I have the same problem, are there any updates by now? :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem removing `types` from `tsconfig.app.json`.
This is the new configuration:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "module": "es2015",
        "baseUrl": ""
    },
    "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `import * as toastr from 'toastr'` or `import toastr from 'toastr'` - the latter is if it has a default export.