# use npm package in Angular 2 component

Tags: angular, npm, package

I would like to use an available npm package in my Angular 4 component but am struggling to make it work.  The package is called 'ip' available from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip

I have added the package as follows:

> npm install ip --save
>
> npm install --save @types/ip

and in my app.module.ts I have:

```
import { isV4Format } from 'ip';
```

and I add isV4Format to the imports list in app.module.ts

I then try to use the ip package it in my class as follows:

```
import { isV4Format } from 'ip';

export class TabValidator {
    private static _check(address: string): any {
        const ip = require('ip');
        if (!myip.isV4Format(address)) { return { 'wrongFormat': true }; }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about the component:

> Cannot find name 'require'

and about app.module.ts:

> Argument of type '{ declarations: (typeof InterfacesComponent | typeof EditnicComponent | typeof AppComponent)[]; i...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the above?  I suspect there are a few things wrong.  I found 2 similar question on SO but they appear to be for different angular versions.

Comment: I tried 'npm install @types/node' as recommended elsewhere but that didn't help

Comment: try to move require block right below imports like this:

`import ...
const ip = require('ip');`

then use it in function. If it not helped, then write path to js in require block, like `const Highcharts = require('highcharts/highstock');`

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of wrong/outdated answers on SO, including these wrong ones:

> [Cannot find name 'require' after upgrading to Angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104114/cannot-find-name-require-after-upgrading-to-angular4)
>
> [Types not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421367/types-not-found)
>
> [Angular 4: "Cannot find name 'require'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476135/angular-4-cannot-find-name-require)

It seems that Angular has made it easier; just add this into the component where you want to use the node module:

```
export declare let require: any;
const ip = require('ip');
```

Now this may not be the BEST way to achieve what you want, since I read something about using 'require' negatively impacts code sharing or something like that in Angular.  But if someone can post a better answer I'll accept that!