# Angular2 - Private (non git tracked) config

Tags: git, angular, config

I'm getting started with angular 2/4/io. I'm using an API and therefore have a secret API key. I wonder what's the best way to hide such sensitive information so it is not tracked by Git anyhow.

As far as I know, there is no such feature in the framework, like a `config.local.json` or so, that would be ignored by default.

There is the `src/environments` folder, but it doesn't have a smart/composable set of config files either, and I guess I don't want to mess with the Angular default behavior to load environment files. (seems overkill)

So, I was thinking about either make my own `config.local.json` file in src/app. Or somehow modify webpack to inject the variables at the right place, but once again it seems to be a lot of work and I don't want to eject webpack for this.

So, what would you recommend? I guess the manual config file is the most straight-forward and simplest way, except if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far was to create in `src/app` a `config.json`, a `config.local.json` (.gitignored) and a `config.interface.ts`

```
export interface Config {
  apiKey: string;
}
```

Then, simply load the config by merging both files.

```
const config: Config = Object.assign({}, require('./config.json'), require('./config.local.json'));
```

I ran into `Cannot find name 'require'` but this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43129815/2391795) helped me.