# Typescript error - Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic app in Angular/Typescript.

I'm using a library called `emojiRegex` and I'm a little uncertain how to use it.

I'm importing it like this:

```
import { emojiRegex } from 'emoji-regex';
```

and then according to the docs you have to `require` it?

So I'm doing:

```
let emojiRegex = require('emoji-regex');
if(emojiRegex().test(this.emoji)) {
```

which works, but I get a typescript error I'd like to remove..

I read you need to add to your `tsconfig.json:

```
"types": [
  "node"
],
```

and then run `npm install @types/node --save-dev` which I did, but it didn't work for me. I just get another error that states:

> [10:39:24]  typescript error
>               Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.

So any ideas how I can do this? I feel like I'm missing something pretty simple.. Thanks!

Comment: seen this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104114/cannot-find-name-require-after-upgrading-to-angular4

Comment: @AshishRanjan that did not work :/ i get that `Cannot find type definition file for 'node'` error

Comment: try giving types as: `"types": []`

Comment: @AshishRanjan that removed the `node` error but it still doesn't allow `require`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to import it as a const like so:

```js
import * as emojiRegex from 'emoji-regex';
```