# Angular 6 - Load JSON from local

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to load a local JSONfile of two ways.

This is my json file:

```
{
  "imgsesion": "fa_closesesion.png",
  "texthome": "volver a la home",
  "logo": "fa_logo.png",
  "menu": {
    "background": "orange",
    "link1": "ESCRITOR",
    "link2": "MÚSICO",
    "link3": "AYUDA ADMIN",
    "submenu": {
      "link1": {
        "text1": "novelas",
        "text2": "obras de teatro"
      },
      "link2": {
        "text1": "compositor",
        "text2": "intérprete"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- Way 1: Using Http

This is my service file (general.service.ts)

```
  getContentJSON() {
    return this.http.get('assets/json/general.json')
    .map(response => response.json());
  }
```

This way working ok, but shows the next error in the web browser console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of undefined
```

- Way 2: Using HttpClient

This is my service file (general.service.ts)

```
  getContentJSON() {
    return this.httpClient.get("assets/json/general.json");
  }
```

It does not work because I can not find the general.json file, it goes through the control of the error and it gives me an error 404

This is the component file (app.component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  contentGeneral: any;

ngOnInit() {
this.getContentJSON();
}

  getContentJSON() {
    this.generalService.getContentJSON().subscribe(data => {
      this.contentGeneral = data;
    }, // Bind to view
    err => {
      // Log errors if any
      console.log('error: ', err);
    });
  }

}
```

This is the template file (`app.component.html`):

```
<a href="#" routerLink="/home" class="linkHome">{{contentGeneral.texthome}}</a>

<div class="submenu" *ngIf="linkWrite.isActive || isSubMenuWriter">
    <span class="d-block text-right small">{{contentGeneral.menu.submenu.link1.text1}}</span>
    <span class="d-block text-right small">{{contentGeneral.menu.submenu.link1.text2}}</span>
</div>
```

This is my actual error:

In app.component.ts, I add the import:

```
import * as data_json from './assets/json/general.json';
```

But when I launch ng serve it gives me the following error:

[image]

How I could resolve it?

Comment: There is another way to do it. 
You may create an exported json inside a .ts file and import it to your component.

Then you may to access to thet json in your component

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The simplest solution:

```
import "myJSON" from "./myJson"
```

**Important update!**

I found, that this method stops working in newest Angular versions, because of this error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.weather.service.ts(2,25): error TS2732: Cannot find module './data.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension

To make it works, go to the tsconfig.json and add this two, inside

compilerOptions( tsconfig.json ) :

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

After change, re-run `ng serve`.

If you only use the first option, you can get an error like this:

> ERROR in src/app/app.weather.service.ts(2,8): error TS1192: Module '"....app/data/data.json"' has no default export.

(I found this very good answer here (https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-read-local-json-files-in-angular/))

Comment: ./src/app/app.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/json/general.json'

Comment: This is the new import: import * as json from './assets/json/general.json';

Comment: I have seen that I have to add a declare code in the file typings.d.ts but this file in Angular 6 I think it does not exist anymore

Comment: Also I have tested with import { data_json } from './assets/json/general.json'; and I get the same error

Comment: import * as data from "./products.json";

console.log(data.property)

Comment: When I add the import in app.component.ts, it happens as indicated in the image that I just added.

Comment: Exactly, the problem is the path and I think the rules of the tsint.json file, thank you

Comment: Important point about adding the typings.d.ts in Angular 6 https://stackoverflow.com/a/51040468/1845580
You have to create the file and then add the custom typing file to typeRoots in tsconfig.json "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/typings.d.ts"],

Comment: esModuleInterop should not be required anymore https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25400

Comment: In my limited testing, doing it this way doesn't allow the json file to be interchangeable?

Answer (score 16):

By this way...

```
import "file" from "./file.json"
```

I got red line and got error like module not found by angular.

After some RND I got another way which works for me. Hope it may help someone.

```
var data = require('src/file.json');
console.log("Json data : ", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: it should be `JSON.stringify(data)` I guess.

Comment: Opps it's typo mistake. @UlianaPavelko

Comment: Thanks. This method worked for me. I got the "Typescript : require statement not part of an import statement" and solved it by changing the solution to `import data = require('your_file.json')`

Comment: using "require" in angular needs the following considerations - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104114/cannot-find-name-require-after-upgrading-to-angular4

Answer (score 8):

For the **Angular 2, Angular 4 and Angular 5**, you can use following method to load your local `.json` files to the component.

```
const data = require('../../data.json');

export class AppComponent  {
    json:any = data;
}
```

To use `require` with in your component, you needed to install `@types/node` by running

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Do the following configuration change under `tsconfig.app.json` > `compilerOptions`

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "types": ["node"],
  ...
},
```

After **Angular 6**, you can use direct imports form file system as follows.

```
import data  from '../../data.json';

export class AppComponent  {
    json:any = data;
}
```

Do the following configuration change under `tsconfig.app.json` > `compilerOptions`

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  ...
},
```

Answer (score 4):

[See this article](https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/loading-json-on-stackblitz-with-angular-bf77a1da3f8a):

```
import data  from './data.json';
export class AppComponent  {
    json:any = data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following code snippet:

```
declare const require;
const locale = localStorage.getItem('locale');
require(`./file.${locale}.json`)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are requesting a JSON file asynchronously, you can handle with safe navigation operator or using ngIf,

```
<div class="submenu" *ngIf="linkWrite.isActive || isSubMenuWriter">
                  <span class="d-block text-right small">{{contentGeneral?.menu?.submenu?.link1?.text1}}</span>
                  <span class="d-block text-right small">{{contentGeneral?.menu?.submenu?.link1?.text2}}</span>
                </div>
```

or simply import the JSON file in your component and assign sampleJSON.

```
import "sampleJSON" from "./sampleJSON"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Open `tsconfig.json` add following lines in `compilerOptions`:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

**Step 2:** import json using following code:

```
import homeData from './data.json';
```

**Note:** This code is tested with Angular 9

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer** - 
[Angular 5 Service to read local .json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206924/angular-5-service-to-read-local-json-file/57574191#57574191)

In **tsconfig.json**

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create .ts file then copy contents of your json file there and add

```
export const <objectName> =
```

something like this

```
export const faceProfilesSample =
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "depth": 0,
  "burden": null
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "depth": 1.97,
  "burden": 8.58
},
```

then you can access it by using objectName with import statement like this

```
import { faceProfilesSample } from "@app/model/face-profiles-sample";
```

No tsconfig.json changes needed