# Fetching data from json file via service is giving "unexpected end of input" in Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular-services

I am trying to get data from a json file located in assets folder. But instead getting error.

**heroes.service.ts**

```
getPeopleData(): Observable<people[]>{
  return this.http.get<people[]>('assets/data/someData.json');
}
```

**people.interface.ts**

```
export interface people{
    id: number,
    name: string,
    age: number
}
```

**someData.json:**

```
[
    {"id":1, "name": "Jack", "age": 21},
    {"id":2, "name": "Rina", "age": 29},
    {"id":3, "name": "Jonathan", "age": 42}
]
```

**about.component.ts**

```
  peopleData:any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPeople();
  }

  getPeople(): void {
   this.heroesService.getPeopleData()
    .subscribe(data => this.peopleData = data)
  }
```

**Error:**

[image]

Can someone help me out, where is the problem? There are no errors in console instead.

Comment: can you console.log data and send us the output?  You may not be getting valid JSON back in your request

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, can you please post it?

Comment: added the json file also. Kindly, see.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924901/angular-6-load-json-from-local/50925032

Comment: is that what is returned from getPeople()?

Comment: I have checked with your code it's working fine. might be your json file having an issue. if you upload your code sample any one can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

Service:

```
public testJson(): Observable<people[]>{
        return this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1f5zag").map(res => res.json());
    }
```

(You can actually try it with that url)

component.onInit

```
this.yourService.testJson()
    .subscribe( evt => {
      const ppl:people[] = evt;
      console.log(ppl);
    });
```