# How to import JSON file to Angular library?

Tags: json, angular, rollupjs, ng-packagr

I'm having trouble importing JSON file to my environment file in Angular 7 library.
My `environment.ts` file looks like this:

```
import firebase from './firebase.json';

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase,
};
```

And `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "apiKey": "",
  "authDomain": "",
  "databaseURL": "",
  "projectId": "",
  "storageBucket": "",
  "messagingSenderId": ""
}
```

But unfortunately when running `ng build` it fails:

```
> sdk@0.0.0 build <path-to-project>/sdk
> ng build sdk

Building Angular Package
Building entry point 'sdk'
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015

BUILD ERROR
Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.transform (<path-to-project>/sdk/node_modules/rollup-plugin-json/dist/rollup-plugin-json.cjs.js:18:20)
    at <path-to-project>/sdk/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:20962:25

Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.transform (<path-to-project>/sdk/node_modules/rollup-plugin-json/dist/rollup-plugin-json.cjs.js:18:20)
    at <path-to-project>/sdk/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:20962:25
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sdk@0.0.0 build: `ng build sdk`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sdk@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     xxx/.npm/_logs/2019-04-10T13_40_47_486Z-debug.log
```

I've tried already:

1) Adding to `tsconfig.json`

```
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"noImplicitAny": false,
```

2) Adding `typings.d.ts` with

```
declare module '*.json' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

3) Changing `import` to `require`

But no luck so far.

My devDependencies include:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.13.8",
"@angular/cli": "~7.3.6",
"@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.2.12",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.12",
...
```

Comment: Try creating a static JSON file and importing it, probably an issue with your file or JSON format.

Comment: Can you add firebase.json as well?

Comment: Added firebase.json. It was working fine in my app, but I would like to import it to angular library sdk and that's where it fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 - Load JSON from local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924901/angular-6-load-json-from-local)

Comment: Unfortunately none of the answers there solve my problem (which seems to be different).

Comment: Your setup looks fine, I wonder if the problem is related to environment file rewrite? Can you try and import the json and log it in another file, not environment?

Comment: So I tried to import JSON file to one of my services in the library. The build still fails. I also tried to make the file completely empty, still the same thing...

Comment: May be check the issues at rollup-plugin-json, like [this one](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel/issues/48#issuecomment-211025960). If nothing helps open an issue with them, they might help.

Answer (score 10):

After a lot of suffering we found that solution [here](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/pull/1125).

It's basically what you've done in the first try, but you need to add one option more.

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,  
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

Additionally:

```
"annotateForClosureCompiler": false
```

Note: for the last prop, that's the same file but instead of adding it to the `compilerOptions`, add it to `angularCompilerOptions`

Comment: Nope, still have the "Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0"

Comment: I add exactly the same issue and disabling `annotateForClosureCompiler` on `angularComplierOptions` fix it.