# How to read Json file in TypeScript (Angular)?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have json file `en.json` with content:

```
{
   "key": "Key"
}
```

How to use this file and get value by key in template:

```
{{ dict.key }}
```

I have tried:

```
import * as dict from 'en.json';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6 - Load JSON from local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924901/angular-6-load-json-from-local)

Comment: Let me check please

Comment: You need to add `"resolveJsonModule": true` in your **tsconfig.json** file. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59012097/8718377

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the answer to your question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50925032/9590251) if you wanna include json to app bundle itself, which is irrational.

In most cases you'll need to load it asynchronously, json is either in assets directory of the app, or remote server. But to load it you need to use either HttpModule or, preferable, HttpClientModule, i.e.

```
getJson(): Observable<MyJsonType> {
  return this.http.get<MyJsonType>('/assets/my.json');
}
```

Comment: Why is it irrational to include JSON in the app bundle?

Comment: Unless it's within lazy loaded module, it's gonna increase the size of the bundle, which concequently increase app loading time.

Answer (score -3):

Create new variable, and assign value of `dict`, then use that new variable in your template.

**component.ts**

```
dictObj:object= dict
```

**template.html**

```
<p>dictObj.key<p>
```