# Angular 6 - is it a bad idea to use "declare var require: any"?

Tags: angular, typescript

I was wondering what the negative consequences of this might be, since it's obviously circumventing the intended typing system used by Angular.

For reference, I'm using it so that I can use `require`.

Does anyone know why this might be a good/bad idea?

edit: I'm not asking about how to use this or what the alternatives are (which I've seen, and I recognize that would make this a duplicate question). I'm specifically, and ONLY, asking how this could negatively impact Angular's inner workings and reliance on TS typings. I did not see that specific question answered in any of the similar posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find name 'require' after upgrading to Angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104114/cannot-find-name-require-after-upgrading-to-angular4)

Comment: The same negative consequences of circumventing typings for anything. You could possibly use the type incorrectly, and it wouldn't be caught until runtime.

Comment: `declare var` seems to me to channel through other third party library written in `Javascript` but anything to do with `Angular`. The consequence only depends on how compatible between this third party library and angular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is TypeScript and why would I use it in place of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript)