# Angular Material (8) S2591: Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to log date/time into the javascript console. The error message I am getting is as follows and was generated by the code below.

**ETA:** the code does work. The dates are going to the console. It is just the Error Message remains

**Message:**

> ERROR in src/app/kdc/services/customers.api.service.ts(60,9): error
> TS2591: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type
> definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to
> the types field in your tsconfig.

NOTE: I have already made changes to the `tsconfig.json` file and have also done `npm i @types/node` and `npm i @types/node --save` When running `npm` result was `3 high-security vulnerabilities` (see below)

[image]

What can I do at this point?`

**customer.api.service.ts**

```
   getCustomers(): Observable<Customers[]> {
        return this.httpclient.get<Customers[]>(this._url)
        .pipe( catchError(this.handleError));
        
    } 

    handleError(error:HttpErrorResponse){
        let rval = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7).toUpperCase();
        require('log-timestamp');
        console.error('MSG NO :' + rval );
        console.error(error);
        return throwError(rval + " <-> " + error.name + " <-> " + error.statusText );
     }
```

**ETA**
I found the message here [Cannot find name 'require' after upgrading to Angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104114/cannot-find-name-require-after-upgrading-to-angular4)  and made the change to my
`tsconfig.app.json` file - it may be overkill, but it worked ...

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [ "node" ],
    "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ]
  },
```

Comment: why you are using log-timestamp Delete this line  require('log-timestamp');

Comment: I was looking for a simple way of recording the timestamp - it works and all. It is just the message keeps popping up.

Comment: If you have a better way of putting timestamps into the log, I am open to listening to  it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Make sure you put the type in your tsconfig.app.json not your tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esNext",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
```

Also make sure your systax in your component look like this

```
const someLib = require("someLib"); // make sure the name is match with your package name
```

Then stop angular cli then run again

Comment: yes, I found an old message - that was exactly the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays you can use ECMAScript import. From

```
const someLib = require("someLib");
```

to

```
import * as someLib from 'someLib';
```