# Can't find module or its corresponding type declarations when trying to import SDK in Angular Project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm-install

Currently attempting to use an SDK in an existing Angular project and we are unable to find the cause to the following problem.

Here is an image of the error:

[image]

`Cannot find module 'flux-sdk' or its corresponding type declarations`

After doing some digging we found various post with the same issue and have tried just about everything we could find and are still unable to solve the error.

Steps...

1. `npm install --save flux-sdk;`
2. `import Flux from 'flux-sdk';`

Fails on `import` ( Step 2 ) with the error shown above.

We are not sure why this is happening and because we have tried the other solutions found online and unable to solve the issue I come here.

Comment: Does the `flux-sdk` NPM package have type declarations included? If it doesn't, did you install the `@types/flux-sdk` package as a dev dependency?

Comment: Close the IDE and reopen it, make a `npm install` after reopen and then start the frontend `ng serve`. I also had the problem that the modules where imported were not found and carried out exactly these steps and this removed this message

Comment: @Edric no types

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I tried this and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could achieve adding typing for a package which doesn't have type definition like this package `flux-sdk` in an Angular project by following steps:

- Create a `typings` directory at the root level then create the typing for this package which is likely called `flux-sdk.d.ts`:

`typings/flux-sdk.d.ts`:

```js
declare module 'flux-sdk' {
  const flux: any; // you can define whatever is now exported
  export default flux;
}
```

- Then just include `typings` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
  },
  "include": [
    "typings"
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try these solutions.

***Method 1:***
Simply use `require` instead of `import`.

```js
// import { Flux } from 'flux-sdk'
const Flux = require('flux-sdk');
```

***Method 2:***
Try to replace these line in the `tsconfig.json` if you want use `import`

```
"noImplicitAny": false,
"allowJs": true,
```

I hope they would help you, thanks.

Comment: I tried this and it still doesnt work. I get the following error ...    ```ERROR in src/main.ts:5:14 - error TS2591: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.  5 const Flux = require('flux-sdk');```

Comment: Please refer this question and answer to fix above error.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237785/angular-material-8-s2591-cannot-find-name-require

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use old package-lock.json. Please delete package-lock.json&node_modules and reinstall node modules.