# How to access Angular CLI 'ng start' command line variable from within angular app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

**Angular 11**

I know that this question has been asked before but I can find no satisfactory answer.

In angular Cli I want to run the command

```
ng serve -o  --client=someclient
```

within an component.ts file or a service.ts file I want to access the client variable thus

```
if (client){
    this.loadClientConfig(client);
} else {
    this.loadClientConfig('whitelabel');
}

loadClientConfig(c){
    // go load the client config section from a config.json file if it exists (this bit i know how to do)
}
```

I know this can *be done* by adding --configuration=someClient but as far as I can tell I then need to add a new configuration section to the angular.json file and a new environment.ts file for every client and I don't want to have to do that.

is there a way to do this?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone else needs to know.

There are 4 steps to achieve this;-

**Step 1. add/edit script in package.json** (example here is ng serve but can be a build etc)

```
"start":"node set-tenant.js --tenant=somevalue && ng serve -o"
```

**Step 2. create set-tenant.js file in the root**

```
console.info('Attempting to set  "tenant" variable in index.html');
let tenant = null;
const indexHtml = 'src/index.html';
process.argv.forEach(a => {
  if (a.startsWith('--tenant')){
    tenant = a.split('=')[1];
  }
});
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile( indexHtml, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err){ return console.error(err); }
  if (data.length){
    console.info('Setting  "tenant" variable in index.html to ' + tenant);
    const matchRule = /\/\*tenant-start\*\/.*\/\*tenant-end\*\//g;
    fs.writeFile( indexHtml, data.replace( matchRule, `/*tenant-start*/window['tenantId'] = '${tenant}';/*tenant-end*/`), 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
    });
  } else {
    return console.error(indexHtml + ' has no content');
  }
});
```

**Step 3. add code to index.html file**

```
<script>/*tenant-start*/window['tenantId'] = 'gtr';/*tenant-end*/</script>
```

**Step 4. access the tenant variable in your TS component and service files**

```
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
this.tenant = window['tenantId'];
```

Comment: this post shows how to add variables into angular code, and that helps me a lot, thank you! I also refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/66671453/560773 that use js file system module to generate ts with variables automatically, you may want to check it out