# How to obtain version in angular 5

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular5

How i get version from `package.json` ?
I have project angular 5
Angular-Cli: `1.6.7` and npm `5.6.0`

My file enviroment.ts:

```
export const enviroment = {
    VERSION: require('../package.json').version 
  }
```

This file it is in `src/app/enviroment.ts`

The file package.json it is in `src/package.json`

When compile, the angular cannot found the file package.
here is the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../package.json'

I follow this answer, but no success
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907682/how-to-display-app-version-in-angular2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `package.json` located under `src`. By doing  `require('../package.json')` you are looking in to `src/app` folder instead.

So you need go one level up: `VERSION: require('../../package.json').version`