# How to display the version from package.json in angular when built in prod mode

Tags: javascript, json, angular

When I tried to display the version from package.json in local(dev mode) in angular, I was able to do it. for eg

```js
import {version} from '../../package.json';
const VERSION = `${version}-a.a.a-b.b.b`;
```

But, in prod mode, when I tried to do the same, the VERSION value is getting displayed as '[Object object]-a.a.a-b.b.b'. Instead if

> const VERSION = ${version};

The VERSION value is getting displayed properly as '1.0.0'. The issue occurs when I tried to append the version value from package.json to a string in app.module.ts when the app is built in prod mode.

I tried to check the typeof version from package.json, it returned string.

I need to display the version from package.json appended to a string value in app.module.ts in prod mode in angular. kindly help. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907682/how-to-display-the-app-version-in-angular

Comment: HI @saurabh, no it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use environment.ts file for that. try this

```
import { version } from '../../package.json';

export const environment = {
    VERSION: version,
};
```

You can now use environment. `VERSION` constant use in your application.

Comment: In fact I tried to console.log the value, where I get the proper response (1.0.0-a.a.a-b.b.b), but when I tried to display in app, it is showing as '[Object object]'.

Comment: console log version and check what you got? object or just string

Comment: I got the string value in console.log.