# Access package.json from angular library

Tags: angular, package.json

I'm building an angular library and got stuck trying to access `package.json` file in the integrating app.

My purpose is to read the app-version variable from the integrating app.

this is what I thought:

```
import { version } from '../../../../../../package.json';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppVersionService {

  private version: string = version;

  getVersion() {
    return this.version;
  }
}
```

Logically I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: error TS6059: File 'C:/.workspace/app-versioning/package.json' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\.workspace\app-versioninge\projects\app-versioning\ng-core'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

P.S: I need to load just the app-version variable into the browser, not the whole `package.json` file.

Any Ideas, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `require` to obtain the file `package.json`.

One good and clean practice is to exported using the environment. To do this just request the file in environment.ts, and export the data you want, something like this

```
const packageJson = require('../../package.json');
export const environment = {
  ..
  version: packageJson.version
}
```

Of course you have to correct the number `..` to the file.

*UPDATE*:

[angular-ngrx-material-starter](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter)

This angular starter project include interesting tools for development and several good practices including the one I mention in the answer. I thought it is was worth to add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! But this loads the whole content of package.json.
I need just the app-version variable.

Comment: But is a json file, you can't access just one property, you need to load the whole file and then keep the things you need.

Comment: It can be done with import. take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907682/how-to-display-the-app-version-in-angular

Comment: I see .. add the structure of you project to the question please