# Executing a JavaScript file when running ng build

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, angular, typescript

I would like to run a JavaScript file in my Angular application every time I run `ng build`. To be more precise, I want this file to be executed before the build process so that the changes that it makes are present in the build.

Its a simple script that reads the app version and its dependencies and write them to an object.

The file is called `pre-build.js` and I have tried configuring the `build` command in `package.json` as follows, however I can see that the script was not executed:

```json
{
   ...
   ...,
   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "node pre-build.js && ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
   },
   ...,
   ...,
}
```

The path of the script is `./pre-build.js`.
I assume that I have to change more configurations in order to achieve this but I am not able to find out where. Any leads will be appreciated.

**Edit:**

This is the content of `pre-build.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const appVersion = require('./package.json').version;
const appDeps = JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').dependencies);

const versionFilePath = path.join(__dirname + '/src/environments/version.ts');

const src = `export const version = '${appVersion}';\nexport const buildTime = '${new Date()}';\nexport const deps = ${appDeps};`;

// ensure version module pulls value from package.json
fs.writeFile(versionFilePath, src, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

When I run `node pre-build.js` in the terminal, the code works fine and updates the `version.ts` file. But i want to somehow automatically execute this command every time i run `ng build`. Which so far i was not able to do so.

Comment: I see where the issue I believe. fs.writeFile is asynchronous so you probably want to wait for that to execute before you do your ng build
There is multiple ways to do that, you can instead fo fs.writeFileSync to make sure it holds there, or you could chain with ng build after it actually finished writing to the file.

Comment: @ErenYeager Thanks for the tip, but this is still not solving the problem. Still when I run `ng build`, the `node pre-build.js` is simply ignored as the `version.ts` file is not updated at all. My guess is that its a configuration issue but im not able to solve it.

Comment: I'll try to setup something locally to try to reproduce, will update my answer accordingly if I find anything

Comment: It's actually super silly, updating my answer ^^" , I didn't pick it up by reading but helped with local testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

The correct answer to this problem is that you shouldn't run `ng build` but should run `npm run build` since you want to execute the script. When you do `ng build` this would only trigger the build for angular and wouldn't update your version file indeed.

Below is an example of your exact same code when doing `npm run build`, so make sure to update how you build.

[image]

Give it a try and let me know if this is still an issue.

---

**Old answer**

You can create a ".sh" script to other execute everything you need. This might be helpful later on to add more pre or post build commands

Here is an example

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "build:angular": "ng build",
  "build": ./build.sh
}
```

build.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
node ./pre-build.js

npm run build:angular
```

Make sure that pre-build is executable so is the build.sh (chmod https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-a-termi )

Comment: Sorry I did not understand how should the `package.json` file be modified? I mean, should `"angular:build": "ng build"` also be placed under `"scripts"`? or?

Comment: yes correct, you'd have : 
`
 "scripts": {
   "angular:build": "ng build",
   "build": "./build.sh"
}
....
`

Then have build.sh at the same level where prebuild is.

You can then just run everything by doing `npm run build` in your command line.

If that doesn't work still, do you mind sharing the following : 
`ls -la .` from your root the result, just to make sure your scripts are executable.

Also what's in your pre-build ? Do you have some kind of logs to tell you if that ran or not ?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I accepted the answer as it perfectly answered the question. But I think I have to formulate a new question as my final goal was a bit beyond the scope of this question. In short,  I use `@angular/fire` to deploy my website, and since `ng deploy` runs `ng build` as well, I wanted to run this JS script within by the `ng build` command that is executed by `ng deploy`.

Comment: I see, yes it wasn't clearly defined in the first question, feel free to open another issue and I can follow up on there if you want.

Looking at this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11787, this is like prehooks to build but not supported as far as I know. You could as well create your own builder ( changing the ng build ), but seems like overcomplicated for what you are trying to achieve here.

I think the easiest way for you might be to, Run your prebuild separately ? Before you run ng deploy ? `"deploy": "node ./pre-build.js && ng deploy"`
And do `npm run deploy`

Comment: Yes, i think this would be the most feasible solution

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
node ./pre-build.js && ng build
```

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: Does it show some log? It’s kinda hard to figure out what’s going on without any console output. Can you show us it?

Comment: I updated the question with the code