# Angular library - export package.json version

Tags: angular, angular-library, npm-version

I created an NX workspace containing multiple libraries and a single showcase-application that's being uploaded to the webserver. I would like to show the library version on the angular application.

[image: Library version is being shown in the application]

### At the moment I'm doing it like this

Export the `package.json` `version` field from the library:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
export const NgBootstrapVersion: string = require('../package.json').version;
```

Import the constant in the application component:

```
import { NgBootstrapVersion } from '@example/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  versionInfo = NgBootstrapVersion;
}
```

Show the version in the app:

```
<span class="me-2 align-middle">{{ versionInfo }}</span>
```

This seems to work in angular applications inside the same NX workspace.

Problem with this approach is that I'm getting the following error when doing the same in a seperate blank angular application (or NX workspace):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

### Another approach: resolveJsonModule

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59378000/how-to-get-version-from-package-json-in-angular-library)

tsconfig.lib.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "types": [ "node" ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  ...
}
```

index.ts

```
import * as packageJson from '../package.json';
export const NgBootstrapVersion: string = packageJson.version;
```

This gives me the following error:

> Error: Should not import the named export 'version' (imported as 'packageJson') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)
>
> error TS2732: Cannot find module '../package.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension.

Which would require me to modify my `tsconfig.app.json` to solve the second error, which is off course undesired... and still leaves me with the first error.

### How angular does it

You can simply use the following code in your angular application to display the `@angular/core` version:

```
import { VERSION } from '@angular/core';
export const AngularVersion = VERSION.full;
```

The code is [written here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/version.ts), but I can't understand where the version from the specific `package.json` is being extracted and what the `0.0.0-placeholder` is for.

How can I easily make the package version available outside my library? I do use Github Actions.

Comment: Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72403081/executing-a-javascript-file-when-running-ng-build) it might give you an idea of how to approach your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all you need to do is:

- In your angular app, edit your **tsconfig.json**

  - set `"compilerOptions:resolveJsonModule": true`
  - set `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`

Import the version like this:

```
import packageJson from '@angular/core/package.json';
version = packageJson.version;
```